# HTML To PDF Font Resolver

Tags: java, html, css, pdf-generation

I am using ItextFontResolver for displaying fonts via ttf files on to a PDF generated. font is applied on HTML page but font changes are not reflecting on PDF file after implemented :

```
    renderer.getFontResolver().addFont(
                    realPath + "website/" + "fonts/"
                            + fontType + "/" + fontType + ".ttf",
                    BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    renderer.setDocument(url);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(os);
```

CSS code :

```
.wholeDivData{ font-family : Comic Sans MS; }
```

Still changes are not reflecting on PDF generated.